# Vue js pass value to other component

Tags: vue.js

I have this simple script, i can show my food.vue. But how can i pass the value(Apple) to food.vue?

```
<template>
    <component v-bind:is="component"></component>   
</template>

<script>
import Food from '@/views/food'

export default {
    name: 'Food',
    data() {
        return {
            food: 'Apple',
            component: Food,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could pass it as a prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the props to the `component` tag, which will be further passed down to the dynamic component. Say if `Food.vue` has a prop named `food`, then you can create a `food` prop as below:

```
<component v-bind:is="component" :food="food"></component>
```

And the `Food.vue` component will receive a `food` prop as `Apple` in this case.